.Net MAUI Pre-loading data for page
I know this type of question has been asked several times before but I have tried any number of suggested solutions and none work for me.
I am trying to load data about authors into a Collection so that I can select one and show further information.  I'm stuck at the stage of preloading the author data.  Here is my code:
MainPage.xaml
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8" ?>
    
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Combox.ViewModels"
             xmlns:library ="clr-namespace:Library"
             x:Class="Combox.MainPage"
             x:Name="mainView">
    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <local:MainViewModel />
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <ContentPage.Behaviors>
        <toolkit:EventToCommandBehavior
        EventName="Appearing"
        Command="{Binding GetAuthorsCommand}" />
    </ContentPage.Behaviors>
    <ScrollView>
        <VerticalStackLayout
            Padding="30,0"
            Spacing="25">
            <Image
                Source="dotnet_bot.png"
                HeightRequest="185"
                Aspect="AspectFit"
                SemanticProperties.Description="dot net bot in a race car number eight" />

            <Label
                Text="Hello, World!"
                Style="{StaticResource Headline}"
                SemanticProperties.HeadingLevel="Level1" />

            <Label
                Text="Welcome to &#10;.NET Multi-platform App UI"
                Style="{StaticResource SubHeadline}"
                SemanticProperties.HeadingLevel="Level2"
                SemanticProperties.Description="Welcome to dot net Multi platform App U I" />
            <toolkit:Expander IsExpanded="{Binding IsOpened}">
                <toolkit:Expander.Header>
                    <HorizontalStackLayout MaximumHeightRequest="42" Padding="10">
                        <Label HorizontalOptions="Start" Text="{Binding SelectedText}" />
                        <Label Text="&#9660;" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Center" />
                    </HorizontalStackLayout>
                </toolkit:Expander.Header>

                <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding DataList}" HeightRequest="190" SelectionMode="Single"
                                SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}" 
                                SelectionChangedCommand="{Binding SelectionCommand}">
                    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Label Text="{Binding FullName}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                </CollectionView>
            </toolkit:Expander>
            <Label Text="End of the page" />
        </VerticalStackLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</ContentPage>

MainViewModel.cs
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Input;
using Library;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows.Input;
namespace Combox.ViewModels
{
    public partial class MainViewModel : ObservableObject
    {
        string _selectedText = "Select the item";
        public string SelectedText
        {
            get { return _selectedText; }
            set { SetProperty(ref _selectedText, value); }
        }
        public Author? SelectedItem { get; set; }
        bool _isOpened = false;
        public bool IsOpened
        {
            get { return _isOpened; }
            private set { SetProperty(ref _isOpened, value); }
        }

        ObservableCollection<Author>? _dataList;
        public ObservableCollection<Author>? DataList
        {
            get { return _dataList; }
            private set { _dataList = value; }
        }

        public ICommand SelectionCommand { private set; get; }
        public AuthorService? AuthorService { get; private set; }

        LibraryFunctions? LibraryFunctions { get; set; }

        public MainViewModel()
        {
            AuthorService = new AuthorService();
            LibraryFunctions = new LibraryFunctions();
            AuthorService.authorsCollection = LibraryFunctions.authorsCollection;
            SelectedItem = new Author();

            SelectionCommand = new Command(
                 execute: () =>
                 {
                     IsOpened = false;
                     Author temp = SelectedItem;
                     SelectedText = SelectedItem.FullName!;
                     Debug.Write($"chosen {temp.FullName}");
                     RefreshCanExecutes();
                 },
                 canExecute: () =>
                 {
                     IsOpened = true;
                     return true;
                 }
            );
            Debug.WriteLine($"author {DataList![20].FullName}");

        }
        void RefreshCanExecutes()
        {
            ((Command)SelectionCommand).ChangeCanExecute();
        }
        [RelayCommand]
        private async Task GetAuthors()
        {
            List<Author> source = new List<Author>();
            source = await AuthorService!.getAuthors("last");
            if (source == null || source.Count == 0)
            {
                Debug.Write("no authors");
                throw new Exception("no authors");
            }

            this.DataList = new ObservableCollection<Author>(source)!;
            Debug.WriteLine($"author {DataList![20].FullName}");
        }

    }

}
SmallLibrary.cs
using MongoDB.Bson;
using MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Attributes;
using MongoDB.Driver;
using MongoDB.Driver.Linq;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace Library
{
    [BsonIgnoreExtraElements]
    public class Author
    {
        [BsonId][BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)] public ObjectId _id { get; set; }
        [BsonElement("first")] public string? first { get; set; }
        [BsonElement("last")] public string? last { get; set; }
        [BsonElement("author_id")] public BsonInt32? author_id { get; set; }
        [BsonElement("FullName")][BsonIgnoreIfNull] public string? FullName { get; set; }

    }
    [BsonIgnoreExtraElements]
    public class Book
    {
        [BsonId][BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)] public ObjectId _id { get; set; }
        [BsonElement("title")] public string? title { get; set; }
        [BsonElement("title_id")] public BsonInt32? title_id { get; set; }
        [BsonElement("author")] public string? author { get; set; }
        [BsonElement("issue_date")] public string? issue_date { get; set; }
        [BsonElement("return_date")] public string? return_date { get; set; }
    }
    public class AuthorService
    {

        public IMongoCollection<Author>? authorsCollection;
        public async Task<List<Author>?> getAuthors(string order = "first")
        {
            IMongoQueryable<Author> results = from author in this.authorsCollection.AsQueryable()
                                              orderby author.last, author.first
                                              select author;
            List<Author>? authors = await results.ToListAsync();
            if (authors == null)
            {
                return null;
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (Author author in authors)
                {
                    if (order == "first")
                    {
                        author.FullName = author.first + " " + author.last;
                    }
                    else if (order == "last")
                    {
                        author.FullName = author.last + ", " + author.first;
                    }
                    else { throw new Exception("Unknown order ${order}"); }
                }
                authors!.Insert(0, new Author() { FullName = "" });
                return authors;
            }

        }
        public async Task<string> GetAuthorName(string _id)
        {
            ObjectId makeId = new ObjectId(_id);
            IMongoQueryable<Author> results = from author in this.authorsCollection.AsQueryable()
                                              where author._id == makeId
                                              select author;
            List<Author> authorList = await results.ToListAsync();
            string name = "";
            foreach (Author author in authorList)
            {
                name = author.first + " " + author.last;
            }
            return name;
        }
        public async Task<string?> GetAuthorId(string? first, string? last)
        {
            IMongoQueryable<Author> results = from a in authorsCollection.AsQueryable()
                                              where a.first == first && a.last == last
                                              select a;
            Author? author = await results.FirstOrDefaultAsync();
            if (author == null)
            {
                return null;
            }
            else
            {
                return author._id.ToString();
            }
        }
    }

    public class BookService
    {
        public MongoCollectionBase<Book>? booksCollection;
        public async Task<List<Book>> getRecent(AuthorService authorService)
        {
            IMongoQueryable<Book> results = (from book in booksCollection.AsQueryable()
                                             orderby book.return_date descending, book.title ascending
                                             select book).Take(10);
            List<Book> results1 = await results.ToListAsync();
            return results1;
        }
        public async Task<List<Book>> getBooksForAuthor(string author_id)
        {
            IMongoQueryable<Book> results = from book in booksCollection.AsQueryable()
                                            where book.author == author_id
                                            orderby book.title
                                            select book;
            return await results.ToListAsync();
        }
        public async Task<List<Book>?> GetBookDetails(string? title, string? authorId)
        {
            IMongoQueryable<Book>? results = from book in booksCollection.AsQueryable()
                                             where book.title == title && book.author == authorId
                                             select book;
            return await results.ToListAsync();
        }
    }

    public class LibraryFunctions
    {
        private MongoClient mongoClient;
        public MongoCollectionBase<Author> authorsCollection { get; set; }
        public MongoCollectionBase<Book> booksCollection { get; set; }
        public MongoDatabaseBase database { get; set; }
        public BookService BookService { get; set; }
        public AuthorService AuthorService { get; set; }
        public string mongodb { get; set; }
        public LibraryFunctions()
        {
            mongodb = "my mongo login details";
            MongoClientSettings settings = MongoClientSettings.FromConnectionString(mongodb);
            settings.LinqProvider = LinqProvider.V3;
            mongoClient = new MongoClient(settings);
            if (mongoClient == null)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Connection to MongoDB failed");
                throw new Exception("Connection to Atlas failed");
            }
            this.database = (MongoDatabaseBase)mongoClient.GetDatabase("library");
            if (database == null)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Connection to database failed");
                throw new Exception("Failed to connect to database");
            }
            this.authorsCollection = (MongoCollectionBase<Author>)database.GetCollection<Author>("authors");
            this.booksCollection = (MongoCollectionBase<Book>)database.GetCollection<Book>("book_titles");
            this.BookService = new BookService();
            BookService.booksCollection = this.booksCollection;
            this.AuthorService = new AuthorService();
            AuthorService.authorsCollection = this.authorsCollection;
        }
        public async Task<List<Book>> _getBooksForAuthor(string author_id)
        {
            return await this.BookService.getBooksForAuthor(author_id);
        }

    }
}

The Library class is just a method of loading the author details and works fine.  I can see this because the Debug statement in the GetAuthors Task gives the correct information.  If I run the app as it stands it does nothing.  If I comment out the Debug in the MainViewModel constructor the app appears but there's no data in the Collection View.  I've tried various methods of loading the author data async but always with the same result.  Is it the {Binding Fullname} that is wrong or is there some other factor I've not taken into account?

make DataList an ObservableProperty

Sorry Jason but it's already an ObservableCollection so I think ObservableProperty isn't valid.

It is.  Because you reassign the value of DataList in GetAuthors(), you are breaking the binding of ItemsSource.  Making DataList Observable should fix that.  An ObservableCollection only raises events when items are added/removed, not when the object itself changes

Hi Jason, if I try to set DataList as an  [ObservableProperty] I get compiler error CS0592 because it is not a field.  As I'm still a beginner with MAUI please give me a hint as to how to resolve this.

I checked in the Community Toolkit for ObservableProperty.  As a result I made the fields _selectedText and _datalist as [ObservableProperty] and removed the definitions for SelectedText and DataList.  These were then automatically generated by the Toolkit.  The list of authors were then displayed within the Expander section as intended.

user3017691 Maybe you miss the topic, Can I answer my own question? From the help center
